# Button Border Color Issues

Tags: html, css, button

I have created a button with the following HTML and CSS code.

```css
.btnstyle2{
    height: 28px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-color: #E8E8E8;
    
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btnstyle2">Dismiss</button>
```

The issues I am having is getting rid of the right and bottom borders that are darker than the left and top borders. I need the entire border for the button to be the light gray that is stated in the CSS code as border-color: #E8E8E8. Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/utdezr2u/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The button is using the default styling. By setting the border to solid will override the default styles.

You can combine the border declaration of width, style and colour into one line like so:

```css
.btnstyle2{
    height: 28px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 2px solid #E8E8E8;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btnstyle2">Dismiss</button>
```

Comment: Is not the width, is the style ... :)

Comment: Depends if you want 1 line or 2 is suppose @MarcosPérezGude :)

Comment: Glad to help @ParkerWilliams.

Comment: You say this: `You need to define the width of the button border.` It is not true, is the style. You can put inline, independently, or what you want, but the width is not the problem ;)

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude i like the tonyedwardspz idea more ;)

Comment: Very true. I have updated the answer @MarcosPérezGude

Comment: @Nabi I don't matter, is the same solution. I learn CSS when this problems are common in CSS version 1. Now is a very uncommon issue, but the solution is same as tony

Comment: @tonyedwardspz your answer is better now ;) I upvoted you

Comment: @ParkerWilliams - if this solved your issue could you mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 5):

You've got a outset style, that's default in buttons (inset in inputs for example).
If you need a solid border add this:

```
 border-style: solid;
```

You can view it:

```css
.btnstyle2{
    height: 28px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-color: #E8E8E8;
    border-style:solid;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btnstyle2">Dismiss</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this for the border.
    border:1px solid #e8e8e8;

Answer (score 2):

Please try this one:

Html

```
<button type="button" class="button1">Demo button</button>
```

Css:

```
.button1{
    height: 28px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#F3F3F3;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-color: #E8E8E8;
    border-style:solid;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/6enghqj6/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Just override the button default class unwanted properties:

```
button {
    align-items: flex-start;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: default;
    color: buttontext;
    padding: 2px 6px 3px;
    border: 2px outset buttonface; /* bad */
    border-image-source: initial;
    border-image-slice: initial;
    border-image-width: initial;
    border-image-outset: initial;
    border-image-repeat: initial;
    background-color: buttonface;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**Example:**

```
.btnstyle2{
    height: 44px;
    width: 46px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-color: #E8E8E8;
    border: none; /* new here */
    background: url('https://www.linkedin.com/scds/common/u/images/logos/linkedin/logo_in_nav_44x36.png') left center no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`border:`** attribute insted of **`border-color:`** which you used to style borders in **`CSS`**. Also you can edit `border-color`, `border-style` on a single line like I have shown below.

**The CSS:**

```
.btnstyle2{
   height: 28px;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: #F8F8F8;
   border:2px solid #E8E8E8;
   border-style:solid;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<button type="button" class="btnstyle2">Dismiss</button>
```