# Why <button> background-color becomes inconsistent across browsers as soon as border is applied

Tags: css, cross-browser, background-color

As shown in my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qdfx9yzu/) demo, the button `background-color` without any styling looks consistent across all browsers - white.

However as soon as `border` is added, the `background-color` becomes inconsistent across browsers(I tested on macOS 10.12.6):

- white in chrome 62.0.3202.94, which is expected
- light grey in FF 57.0, which is slightly unexpected
- dark grey in safari 11.0.1, which is highly unexpected

Can someone explain to me why? Is this a bug of safari?

Comment: I think that by adding a border, you are overwriting the button's default style.  Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32009486/button-border-color-issues) could help you.

Comment: You are seeing default browser styles - they differ in each browser.

Comment: They don't differ when there's no `border` though.

Comment: I see the problem - the button with the border looks different across browsers. However, the first button is not white in any of my browsers, so you may want to remove that bit from the question.

Answer (score 0):

**That's because once `border` is specified, the native appearance of `<button>` element (the one with operating system's look & feel) is disabled, and a completely new default look & feel would be applied.**

Unfortunately, different browsers have different interpretation on what this "new look & feel" should be -- Safari choose to define background of button as "dark grey" for this "new look & feel", it's not a bug.

According to [an announcement of WebKit in 2005](https://webkit.org/blog/28/buttons/):

> Specifying the background/border will result in the Aqua appearance being disabled and a more platform-neutral look being used.

Thus, `border` property can be used like a switch -- a switch that can convert button between 2 appearance modes: one is operating system level button which is stereoscopic but hard to customize. Another is platform-neutral, simple but easy to apply CSS.

Actually, this is what Bootstrap did to customize its button styles. In Bootstrap's `_buttons.scss` source code, the `.btn` button class has a `border` property as `1px solid transparent;` -- an invisible border which will trigger the platform-neutral mode for further CSS rules.